# LibGDX: AssetManager has asset in queue and is updating, but is never loading

Tags: java, libgdx, assets

FIX: Converting the models to g3db format fixed the issue.

I am using Java 1.8.0_60, Android 6.0

So I've decided to have a go at 3D in LibGdx, and I'm running into some weird issues with the AssetManager.

I've been following tutorials pretty much completely so far, and am trying to load a .obj model of a ship I got from one of the tutorials.

I am creating the AssetManager and adding the .obj file to the queue, with Model.class as the second parameter of the load method.

I am then waiting for the asset to load, calling update() on the AssetManager each render to check whether it has loaded.

Right now, my printlns are pretty much looking like this:

Assets in queue: 1

Progress: 0.0

My render method looks like this (In GameRenderer class):

```
public void render(){

    if(!created){
        return;
    }

    if(assets.loading() && assets.update()){
        assets.bindModels();
    }
    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(assets.getInstances(), environment);
    modelBatch.end();

}
```

And my asset loading methods look like this (in AssetLoader class):

```
public void loadModels(){   
    assets.load("ship.obj", Model.class);
    loading = true;
}

public void bindModels() {
    ModelInstance model = new ModelInstance(assets.get("ship.obj", Model.class));
    instances.add(model);
    loading = false;
}

public boolean update(){
    System.out.println("Assets in queue: " + assets.getQueuedAssets());
    return assets.update();
}
```

There are no exceptions being thrown.

My guess is that something is causing the AssetManager to jam, but I'm lost on what could be causing it.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

If I call finishLoading() on the AssetManager, which blocks until the assets are all done, the game freezes.

Comment: what is your loading() method? Are you setting *loading* variable to false when loading is finished?

Comment: loading() just gets the loading boolean.  Loading is set to true when the models start loading, and is only set to false in bindModels(). AssetManager#update() is always returning false, so for some reason the model isn't actually being loaded.

Comment: ok and is the method running? I mean is `"Assets in queue: "` string showing up in the console?

Comment: From what I understand you are using asset manager wrong. See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets You need to call assetManager.updated() in a loop to actually load assets, but you return when created is false.

Comment: Oh update is being called - the boolean 'created' is for the class initialization, nothing to do with the asset stuff.

Comment: And yeah, "Assets in Queue" is being called/printed every render.

Comment: Can you provide the context on how/when etc.. everything is called? For example, when do you call update from your AssetLoader class, and what is the variable asset, is it the same in both code snippets?

Comment: loadModels is called before any rendering is done, and rendering is done from the main game class.  assets in GameRenderer is an instance of 'AssetLoader' - a helper class for using AssetManager.  assets in AssetLoader is an instance of the actual AssetManager.  Update is called on AssetLoader until the assets are loaded, and passes through the update call to the AssetManager.